# unable to send Email through codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, smtp, wampserver

i am using codeIgniter with wamp as localserver and i write the send Email code

```
 $config = array( 
      'protocol'=>'smtp',
      'smtp_port'=>'465',
      'smtp_host'=>'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
      'smtp_user'=>'myemail@gmail.com',
      'smtp_pass'=>'*********'
    );
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");//set the new line rule 
    $this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'Imran Tufail');
    $this->email->to('myemail@gmail.com');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message("The stuff works");

    if($this->email->send())
    {
         echo "Mail sent ";
    }
    else{
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
    }
```

This code is generating an Error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
```

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

The following SMTP error was encountered: 1706213911 Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i resolve my problem.As we are using ssl smtp and have not enabled ssl extension in wamp server

so go to the wanpserver icon in taskbar,

```
  wampserver->php->phpextansions-> then check the php_openssl extansion
```

Comment: did solved your problem or still  u need any help..........

Comment: thnx venkat my problem is resolved